# "Tagged Questions" page is not showing the question that is tagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I've recently visited [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13725/277) post where you can find the tag [grahas](/questions/tagged/grahas) while clicking on it, the page ["Tagged questions"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grahas) says "**0** questions tagged" and not showing the question that is tagged. Though, while hovering the mouse over tag, it shows 1 question.

[image: screenshot]

So, why is [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grahas) page not showing the tagged question?

<sup>Note that the [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13725/277) is posted 14 hours ago (with respect to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280388) post). so, delay in update of the page is not the issue.</sup>

Comment: oh! same issue with [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jyotish)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, that would seem to be my fault; I think our newly deployed changes to the code that does all the tag filter / combination / exclusion code is having a hard time with *newly added* tags. If I use my dev console to see what it is doing:

```
Parsing query...
query parsed, 0ms
Warning (invalid tags): grahas

Parsing query...
query parsed, 0ms
Warning (invalid tags): jyotish
```

(and with no tags that it considers "valid", it jumps into a "no results" short-cut)

The really odd thing is: it definitely knew about the tag against the question:

```
{
 "Id": 13725,
 "LastActivityDate": "2016-06-17T14:08:24Z",
 "CreationDate": "2016-06-17T14:08:24Z",
 ...
 "Tags": "|vedanta|jyotish|grahas|"
}
```

I've done a "dump" of the raw memory so I can reproduce it locally (just waiting for it to copy over the network), and I've restarted the service which has made it notice it:

```
Parsing query...
query parsed, 0ms
Switching to All over Newest/grahas (1)
Searching >>>: (all) (Newest, 1 candidates)
Filter...
Filter complete, 0ms
1 matches using 1 work units and 1 threads, related tags calculated: True
ran to completion: True (0, 0.0 %, 0 of 1)
SortRelatedTags...
SortRelatedTags complete, 0ms
kept 3 of 3 (3 question-tags)
```

but: this is definitely a bug and will be fixed ASAP.

---

Update: should be fixed now; the problem was that in part of the logic we "pre-explode" the synonyms so that we can quickly go from any tag to the *effective* tag; when new tags were added, the pre-exploded value was left at a default value ("no tag") unless the synonyms were re-exploded, which would happen if the synonyms were changed in some way (or if the data was re-initialized). So the relevant code interpreted the newly added tags as though they hadn't been included.

We now do a better job of handling this when new tags are added!

Comment: Now, I can see that the page is showing that question... Is there any changes made?

Comment: @Pandya "Is there any changes made?" - see "and I've restarted the service which has made it notice it"; my current hypothesis is that a bit of code to update the counts against each tag is being bypassed in some scenario (it should run whenever the data changes)

Comment: @Pandya absolutely! "this is definitely a bug and will be fixed ASAP" - if it is  obvious I might get it done shortly, but: worst case it'll be my number one priority on Monday.

Comment: May I know if it somehow affected older tags? [A recent question on Meta Android.SE](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/temporarily-banned-from-editing-posts) is currently not shown on [questions list](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: @meatball not the same thing, but yes, there appears to be a difference there too; investigating (fixed for now)

Comment: @meatball heh, after a lot of searching, it was an "off by one" error; basically, we dropped *exactly one question* when we loaded the engine. Thanks for spotting that - in this case, 2173 was the last question on the site, hence it fell between the cracks. Pushing out a fix.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for the quick fix, cheers!

Comment: @meatball what else was I going to do with a Saturday, eh? ;)